# Python3.x, How to focus on newly opened webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, macos-high-sierra

Ok, here's the deal. I use:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get = ('http://google.com')
```

to open a new webpage. After opening the new webpage, I use pyautogui to do some clicking and scrolling and whatnot, and then close the browser, and then do the same thing over again as the program iterates through a list of proxies. But when the webpage opens, it isn't in focus. I can see it and see that it opened, but it's not in focus.

So I originally implemented a simple click command on the webpage, and that usually focuses the new browser. But after the first browser is opened and closed, the next browser that is opened using a new proxy from the list isn't in focus, and for whatever reason, the click doesn't bring it into focus. So because the browser isn't in focus, my scroll code doesn't happen, it just acts like it skips over it. So I guess my question is, is there some command I can use to make my program focus on the new browser? I've searched extensively on here for the answer to my question and have tried a bunch of different things, but none have worked. Most answers on here pertain to newly opened tabs, and that isn't my issue. Any helpful comments or ideas would be much appreciated. I'm using Mac OS X, and the most recent version of python. Thank you.

Comment: Anyone have any helpful ideas? Bueller...bueller..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scratch the whole click on the dock icon thing, after extensive testing, that didn't work consistently. However, what did actually work consistently was using pyautogui to click on the "new tab" button at the top, and then close tab, and boom, webpage focused.